# Redirect rule for only home page from http to https

Tags: linux, apache, security

Can we make https for only home page i.e., for

> example.com **or** http://example.com **or** www.example.com **or** http://www.example.com

remaining all pages should start with http.

I have tried like this but it isn't worked

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really tested but should do the magic

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule !^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect like this in a .htaccess at root level:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
Redirect 301 /index.html https://www.website.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not secure. Read [OWASP a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection) and set the [HSTS flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to make your entire website HTTPS only.

HTTP is a mistake and if you are doing this for "performance" you are a fool.  HTTPS is extremely light weight.